# Не видит переменную (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Коллеги. Столкнулся с проблемой, что модуль декодирования баркодов не видит в себе переменные компонента, тем самым не получается записать результат. Как правильно сделать? Помогите пожалуйста =)

```
barcodeReader: function (event) {
        Quagga.decodeSingle({
            numOfWorkers: 0,
            src: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
            decoder: {
                readers: [
                    "code_128_reader",
                    "ean_reader",
                    "ean_8_reader",
                    "code_39_reader",
                    "codabar_reader",
                    "upc_reader",
                    "upc_e_reader",
                    "code_93_reader",
                ]
            },
        }, function (result) {
            if(result){
                if (result.codeResult) {

                    let types = {
                        codabar_reader:'CODABAR',
                        code_39_reader: 'CODE_39',
                        code_93_reader: 'CODE_93',
                        code_128_reader: 'CODE_128',
                        ean_8_reader: 'EAN-8',
                        upc_reader: 'UPC-A',
                        upc_e_reader: 'UPC-E'
                    };

                    this.form.qr = result.codeResult.code;
                    this.form.barcodeType = types[result.codeResult.format];

                } else {
                    alert("Не удалось просканировать баркод");
                }
            }else{
                alert("Баркод не обнаружен");
            }

        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Вынес функцию отдельно - все заработало)

```
barcodeReader: function (event) {
            Quagga.decodeSingle({
                numOfWorkers: 0,
                src: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
                decoder: {
                    readers: [
                        "code_128_reader",
                        "ean_reader",
                        "ean_8_reader",
                        "code_39_reader",
                        "codabar_reader",
                        "upc_reader",
                        "upc_e_reader",
                        "code_93_reader",
                    ]
                },
            }, this.barcodeResult);
        },
        barcodeResult(result) {
            if (result) {
                if (result.codeResult) {

                    let types = {
                        codabar: 'CODABAR',
                        code_39: 'CODE_39',
                        code_93: 'CODE_93',
                        code_128: 'CODE_128',
                        ean_8: 'EAN-8',
                        ean_13: 'EAN-13',
                        upc: 'UPC-A',
                        upc_e: 'UPC-E'
                    };
                    this.form.qr = result.codeResult.code;
                    this.form.barcodeType = types[result.codeResult.format];
                    console.log(result.codeResult.format);
                } else {
                    alert("Не удалось просканировать баркод");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Баркод не обнаружен");
            }
        },
```